# RecyclerView crashes when I update data to Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm showing data from a Firebase Firestore collection, the app worked fine while but when I update data to the collection from other device (I got an Arduino with sensors connected to a PC that executes a Python script to transform the serial data to JSON and then I update that data on the Firestore collection, all the back end of these functionality works perfectly. My problem it's the Java on Android.

I already search for solutions on this forum and It seems like something doesn't work with the Adapter, the RecyclerView and the "notifyDataSetChanged();" None of the current solutions worked for me or maybe I just don't know how to implement them on my project.

This is my model

```
public class Monitor {
    String alias, placa, temp, acid;

    public Monitor(){}

    public Monitor(String alias, String placa, String temp, String acid) {
        this.alias = alias;
        this.placa = placa;
        this.temp = temp;
        this.acid = acid;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    public String getPlaca() {
        return placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(String placa) {
        this.placa = placa;
    }

    public String getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(String temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public String getAcid() {
        return acid;
    }

    public void setAcid(String acid) {
        this.acid = acid;
    }
}
```

The adapter

```
public class MonitorAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Monitor, MonitorAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Activity activity;
    /**
     * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See {@link
     * FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public MonitorAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Monitor> options, Activity activity) {
        super(options);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Monitor model) {
        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
        final String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
        holder.alias.setText(model.getAlias());
        holder.temp.setText(model.getTemp());
        holder.acid.setText(model.getAcid());

        holder.btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(activity, VincularPlaca.class);
                i.putExtra("id_placa",id);
                activity.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_monitor_single,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView alias, temp, acid;
        Button btn_edit;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            alias = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alias);
            temp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp);
            acid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.acid);
            btn_edit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);

        }
    }

}
```

And my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_add, btn_exit;
    RecyclerView mRecycler;
    MonitorAdapter mAdapter;
    FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mRecycler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSingle);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        Query query = mFirestore.collection("dispositivos");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Monitor> firestoreRecyclerOptions =
                new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Monitor>().setQuery(query,Monitor.class).build();

        mAdapter = new MonitorAdapter(firestoreRecyclerOptions, this);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        btn_add = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        btn_exit = findViewById(R.id.btn_close);

        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,VincularPlaca.class));
            }
        });

        btn_exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
                mAuth.signOut();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAdapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no stack-trace, which means the question is insufficient. Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on a new instance of an adapter appears strange to me, as it provides no meaning.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo my Android Studio device manager and emulator is not working correctly so I just build the apk and execute on a physichal device, so I got not access to the logcat when this error happens, but the "crash" it just the app closing itself when I upload data to the collection on firestore. Looking for solutions I found some way to do the document snapshot on another void, related to some "refreshing button" or something, that reads the data again, but also I would have change the recyclerview to a "listview". I don't have experiencie with these stuff I apologize.

Comment: Why have you written mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() when you are using mAdapter.startListening() and mAdapter.stopListening() ?. Doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ExampleViewModel : ViewModel() {
var mFirestore : FirebaseFirestore? = null
private val _list = MutableLiveData<FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Monitor>>()
val list: LiveData<FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Monitor>> = _list

init{
    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    list.value= FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Monitor>().setQuery(mFirestore!!.collection("dispositivos"),Monitor::class.java).build()
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem has solved fixing the AndroidManifest Permissions and outside the code on the Firebase Firestore console, the attribute was supose to be an string but it recieves an int.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).